# Finding Segment information on a Route between 2 places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, route, direction

Is there a way to find Segment information on a Route between 2 places using Google Maps API?

I have 2 places/addresses/latlong. I am looking for the direction between the two. For this direction, I need type information about the segment:

- Is it a road
- Is it a highway
- Is it a bridge
- ...